# Removing sub-tags from XML and create new XML files

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have an XML [input](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UMNRV1ZXepLdWws04WuAFfuq7Ihnc6WR/view?usp=sharing) file which I need to split into multiple files based on `MAPPING` and `WORKFLOW` tags.

Since I have two `MAPPING` tags in my input XML and one `WORKFLOW` tag, I need to generate three files:

- [`m_demo_trans_agg.XML`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UMNRV1ZXepLdWws04WuAFfuq7Ihnc6WR/view?usp=sharing)
- [`m_demo_trans_exp.XML`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UMNRV1ZXepLdWws04WuAFfuq7Ihnc6WR/view?usp=sharing)
- [`wf_m_demo_trans_agg_exp.XML`](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1noLKFqRWFWnUNSj4uKtQ3ksx9xYHmpTO/view?usp=sharing)

So, my mapping file (starting with `m_`) will have tags `SOURCE`, `TARGET`, and `MAPPINGS`. The workflow file will have tags `WORKFLOW` and `CONFIG`.

1. Please let me know how can I create mapping XML.
2. I started with workflow XML creation.

My code looks like:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree  

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
target_node_first_parent = 'FOLDER'
target_nodes = ['SOURCE', 'TARGET', 'MAPPING']

for node in root.iter(target_node_first_parent):
    for subnode in node.iter():
        if subnode.tag in ['SOURCE', 'TARGET', 'MAPPING']:
            print(subnode.tag)
            node.remove(subnode)

out_tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
out_tree.write('output.xml')
```

I am getting the `TARGET` tags in my output.xml.

I am open to using any libraries apart from `xml.etree.ElementTree`.

Please assist.

Thanks

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks

Comment: I am open for any solution in Python.

Comment: Please add desired output XML files to your question

Comment: The input XML is not well-formed. Please fix it.

Comment: given the link for the full xml file.

Comment: Upload a subset of the file (make sure it is valid), explain  how you want to split it.